# trying to access a collection with uid, firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, redux-firestore

I'm using react with firebase/firestore, I'm moving from Angular to React but I'm struggling to access the firestore database without AngularFirestore. I am able to login to firestore and obtain the user.uid, I just can't access the 'pred' collection which is nested inside each user.uid so this data is only for the user.

In Angular I access my database like this: (it works)

```
this.auth.user.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.items = this.db
          .collection("users")
          .doc(this.user.uid)
          .collection("pred")
          .valueChanges();
```

In react I'm trying to do the same collection, doc, collection, but I can't find clear documentation how to do it.

My react attempt:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Dashboard.css";
import { auth, db, logout } from "../../services/firebase/firebase-auth";
import { query, collection, getDocs, where, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
function Dashboard() {
    const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const userId = auth.currentUser?.uid;
        const docRef = collection(db, "users");
        const predictions = collection(db, "pred");
        const predSnapshot = await getDocs(predictions);
        const predList = predSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
        return predList;
    };
```

How can I return the predList which follows:

```
.collection("users")
      .doc(this.user.uid)
      .collection("pred")
```

path order, but using react or just plain javascript? I'm using this **import { query, collection, getDocs, where, doc } from "firebase/firestore";** package but I can't see how to do it.

Comment: Do you not have to get a document from 'pred' collection? In dart/flutter, we use `.snapshots()` to get realtime updates on data

Answer (score 1):

To create a reference to the `pred` subcollection of the current user in the new modular/v9 syntax:

```
collection(db, "users", userId!, "pred")
```

Comment: thanks for sending me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

```
const fetchData = async () => {
        const userId = auth.currentUser?.uid;
        const docRef = collection(db, "users", userId as string, "pred");
        const preds = await getDocs(docRef);
        const predList = preds.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
        console.log(predList);
    };
```